# PHP: I have an associative array (int => object), want to sort it

Tags: php, oop, sorting

```
class DownTime {
    public $total, $longest, $count;
}
```

I have an associative array (key is an id, value is DownTime object).
I want to sort it according to $total
I've read [PHP: Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and some other questions on stackoverflow.

I understand `uasort` will do the job fine. However, as an OOP approach, I would prefer define a special function (like defining `operator<()` in C++, or implementing `Comparable.compareTo()` in Java) inside the DownTime class, rather than passing a function when calling some sort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option while still using the language is to create an iterator collection class that extends [`Iterator`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) instead of using a native array.

Actually, you can also extend [`ArrayObject`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and override the `sort` methods:

```
class MyArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
    public function natsort() {
        $this->uasort(function($a, $b) {
            return $a->total > $b->total ? 1 : -1;
        });
    }
}

$arrayObject = new MyArrayObject($array);
$arrayObject->natsort();

foreach ($arrayObject as $value) {
    //sorted values
}
```

Or if you really need a native array after that:

```
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```

But I find that I usually don't need native arrays where I use iterators/arrayobjects.

Just another alternative to a compare function on the class itself...

Comment: Thanks. natsort was something I thought could possibly be the solution here when I was reading different sorts on php.net. However, as you've stated here, it seems there just isn't a solution elegant enough for my question currently in php. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the [SPL Interfaces](http://us.php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php) are nice, but they really need to implement `Sortable`, `Comparable` and a few others into the language to make it really transparent and powerful.  But for now, this is what we have...

Answer (score 5):

You can define a compare() method on the DownTime class:

```
class DownTime {
    public $total, $longest, $count;
    public static function compare(DownTime $a, DownTime $b) {
        // compare $a and $b here, and return -1, 0, 1
    }
}
```

Then use uasort like this:

```
uasort($array, 'DownTime::compare')
```

There is no such "Comparable" interface in PHP, however it would be quite simple to implement it in useland :

```
interface Comparable {
    function compareTo($a);
}

// a generic compare function
function compare($a, $b) {
    if ($a instanceof Comparable) return $a->compareTo($b);
    if ($a < $b) return -1;
    if ($a > $b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

// now you can sort without knowing anything about what the array contains:
uasort($array, 'compare');
```

And if you want to be able to do this transparently with an ArrayObject:

```
class SortableArrayObject extends ArrayObject
{
    function asort() {
        return $this->uasort('compare'); // you can even make compare() a member of
                                         // SortableArrayObject and use 
                                         // $this->uasort(array($this,'compare'))
    }
}

$arrayObject->asort();
```

Here the container knows nothing about the containee, which is better in a OOP point of view.

Comment: Yes, this is better than defining a function of arbitrary name and forget about it ever. However, I do expect something even better, something that is in the PHP language. Anyway, this is a good solution, especially if this is how PHP programmers do this. Thank you.

Comment: PHP has not such Comparable interface, however it is easy to add one (just added this to my answer).